# hexadecimal to strings using python

Tags: python

i am new to python and trying to convert a list of hexadecimal to string

```
chunk= [' ho', 'w a', 're ', 'you']
chunk_2 = [i.encode('utf-8').hex() for i in chunk]
print(chunk_2)
['20686f', '772061', '726520', '796f75']

chunk_3 = [int(i, base=16) for i in chunk_2]
print(chunk_3)
[2123887, 7807073, 7496992, 7958389]
(convert chunk_3 to hexadecimal)

chunk_4 = [f'{i:x}' for i in chunk_3]
print (chunk_4)
['20686f', '772061', '726520', '796f75']
```

how can i convert hexadecimal chunk_4  back to list of string inchunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bytearray for this.

```
>>> chunk_4 = ['20686f', '772061', '726520', '796f75']
>>> [bytes.fromhex(k).decode() for k in chunk_4]
[' ho', 'w a', 're ', 'you']
```

Comment: `bytes.fromhex` probably more usual, since we don't need a mutable bytearray here.

Comment: Good point.  My Google search came up with the `bytesarray` example, so I just copied it.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please check to see why i get error (UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 2: invalid start byte)

Comment: That says you are trying to translate strings that are not in UTF-8.  You can remove the `.decode()` to see the 8-bit version.  If you know what character you expected it to be, you can figure out what code page you're using and how to do the decode.